# How to find Jobs that ran between two times

Tags: sql-server, jobs

Is there a query to check what a Jobs that ran between to given times. I can check the Jobs that are scheduled between two times but I dont want that.

Example I want to know what the Jobs that ran between `16:00:00` and `17:00:00`

There can be cases where job scheduled at `15:00:00` might running for more than 1 hour I want those as well. I did search in google all I got is jobs those are scheduled between two times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could run the following query to retrieve the jobs run between two times or you could change the `WHERE` expression to catch jobs that ran for a certain duration.

```
SELECT sj.name,
       sjh.step_name,
       sjh.step_id,
       --sjh.run_status,
       STUFF(STUFF(CAST(sjh.run_date as nvarchar(10)),5,0,'.'),8,0,'.') as HistRunDate,
       STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(sjh.run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as HistRunTime,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(sjh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') as HistRunDuration
       --,sjh.run_status AS JobStatus
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs           AS sj
       join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh --- was sysjobschedule sjc
            on sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE  1=1
--AND sj.enabled = 1
------------------------------------------
-- for a certain time frame
------------------------------------------
AND ((sjh.run_date = 20170617 and sjh.run_time > 200000) 
or (sjh.run_date = 20170722 and sjh.run_time < 100000))

------------------------------------------
-- between certain dates and with a long duration
------------------------------------------
--AND (sjh.run_date > 20160501) AND (sjh.run_date < 20160503)
--and sjh.run_duration > 3000

------------------------------------------
-- Job Outcome not required
------------------------------------------
--and sjh.step_name != '(Job outcome)'
--and sjh.step_id = 0

------------------------------------------
-- Find failed jobs
------------------------------------------
--and sjh.run_status != 1


ORDER BY
       sjh.run_date,
       sjh.run_time
```

As [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets) pointed out there are various ways to retrieve the date you require. It's good to know though that the dates and times are defined as `INT` in the `sys.jobsxxxx` tables and not as dates and times as one would expect.

Reference: [dbo.sysjobhistory (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997(v=sql.110).aspx)(Microsoft Technet)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get this information from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table.

Have a look at [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql) about it.

This is the sample you'll find there:

```
SELECT sj.name,
       sh.run_date,
       STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(sh.run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') 'run_time',
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(sh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') 'run_duration (DD:HH:MM:SS)  '
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sh
ON sj.job_id = sh.job_id;

| name                                       | run_date | run_time | run_duration (DD:HH:MM:SS) |
|--------------------------------------------|----------|----------|----------------------------|
| C88FC48A-1F9B-42CB-8D6B-9DB6E394A08F       | 20170601 | 08:00:01 | 00:00:00:00                |
| 25C346F3-C83E-4DAC-9A31-C0A0C8C4B862       | 20170601 | 08:00:01 | 00:00:00:00                |
| C88FC48A-1F9B-42CB-8D6B-9DB6E394A08F       | 20170601 | 08:00:00 | 00:00:00:01                |
| 25C346F3-C83E-4DAC-9A31-C0A0C8C4B862       | 20170601 | 08:00:00 | 00:00:00:01                |
| Copia de seguretat cada 12 hores.Subplán_1 | 20170601 | 12:00:00 | 00:00:01:50                |
| Copia de seguretat cada 12 hores.Subplán_1 | 20170601 | 12:00:00 | 00:00:01:50                |
| 9D523764-6C16-4F35-A623-B0F4AB0DC071       | 20170601 | 15:18:00 | 00:00:00:00                |
| 9D523764-6C16-4F35-A623-B0F4AB0DC071       | 20170601 | 15:18:00 | 00:00:00:00                |
| 3749C767-EB7A-44EB-B1C2-3D2CB04A2B43       | 20170601 | 21:00:00 | 00:00:00:00                |
| 3749C767-EB7A-44EB-B1C2-3D2CB04A2B43       | 20170601 | 21:00:00 | 00:00:00:00                |
```